# tools to make tests independant of used frameworks

Tags: java, testing, frameworks

We use different frameworks for our projects (spring mvc, gwt, tapestry...). So we want to find a framework (or mecanism ?) that enables us to do testing (units and integration) independantly of used frameworks. Is this possible ?

thanks

Comment: Your best friend is interfaces.

Comment: hi Nilsh. can you give me an example for that ? thanks